# Can't get Symfony 3 Console to work - Autoloading Problems

Tags: command-line-interface, symfony, autoloader

I need help with the Symfony 3 Console Component.

I can't get it to work, I always get an fatal error with my custom classes.

Here the code:

*clhelper.php*

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use CLHelper\FilesSorterCommand;

$application = new Application();
$application->add(new FilesSorterCommand());
$application->run();
```

*FilesSorterCommand.php*

```
namespace CLHelper;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Files Sorter
 */
class FilesSorterCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('files:sort')
            ->setDescription('Sortiert Dateien mit bestimmter Endung.')
            ->addArgument(
                'extension',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Welche Dateiendung?'
            )
            ->addArgument(
                'folder',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL | InputArgument::IS_ARRAY,
                'Welche Ordner (Mehrfachangabe möglich)'
            );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $extension = $input->getArgument('extension');

        $output->writeln($extension);
    }
}
```

If I try to run this CL App with `php clhelper.php` I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CLHelper\FilesSorterCommand' not found in /Users/xyz/Sites/Symfony/clhelper/clhelper.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Class 'CLHelper\FilesSorterCommand' not found in /Users/xyz/Sites/Symfony/clhelper/clhelper.php on line 10

Comment: You probably need to adjust the psr4 section of your composer.json file and then rebuild vendor/autoload

Comment: You are right @Cerad. I had to add the PSR4 part to my composer.json. But I can't find this part in the documentation, so I thought I could omit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @cerad comment I added this to my composer.json with success:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "CLHelper\\": ""
    }
}
```

Now it works fine.